# How can reset password of Azure Active Directory?

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory

I have used **AAD** for authentication in my application . I want to reset the password of user through **REST api** . I have user id like *ABCD@onmicrosoft.com*. Do AAD have any default method to update password by passing id or any demo example will be much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset a users password using the [Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations), you want to be looking at the `PasswordProfile` class in C#.

The direct API call would be something like this, not the request is a PATCH not POST or GET:

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version=1.6
```

JSON Body:

```
{
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "MyPa$$w0rd",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  }
}
```

Comment: I have seen that link .I am unable to get from this link. Can you just show me the demo function. It will be helpful

Comment: The request is in the answer above... Submit the JSON to the API and it should be pretty much it.

Comment: @MartynC What does this API do? I tried this request and it returned a 204 response code. I am still able to login using the old password, what is the API doing then?

Comment: @adarshhegde : `204 code`  = password reset successful. Care to share your code in pastebin ?