# How to reset the password of an Azure Active Directory user using UWP platform and C#

Tags: c#, azure, uwp

I found this link on stackoverflow [How can reset password of Azure Active Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595007/how-can-reset-password-of-azure-active-directory).

I am trying to do something similar but I just want to force a user to change the password at the next login. This is the code I have but it is not working.

```
public static class DirectoryPwdReset
{
    const string graphResourceUri = "https://graph.windows.net";
    public static string graphApiVersion = "1.6";

    public static async Task<List<UserPwdReset>> UpdatePassByAlias(string alias, string accessToken, string tenantId)
    {
        List<UserPwdReset> results = new List<UserPwdReset>();

        string graphRequest = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}/{1}/users/{3}?api-version={2}", graphResourceUri, tenantId, graphApiVersion, alias);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), graphRequest);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        var passwordProfile = new
            {
                password = "Test12345",
            forceChangePasswordNextLogin = true
            };

        string serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(passwordProfile);
        request.Content = new StringContent(serializedData, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var json = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            }
        }

        return results;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is not working about it? You are not using the json variable in the response, and you are returning what seems to be an empty List<UserPwdReset>.

Comment: Thanks for everybody's valuable help, got it working myself.